ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas' - I keep getting "kicked" out of my .venv enviornment when running script
Discliamer - I'm new to python.
This error isn't new. I've found many other similar issues. I seems I getting booted from my virtual environment after I run my 'Import pandas as pd' script.
enter image description here
As you can see int this picture, my virtual environment is not running
enter image description here
Here it is with the virt env effectively running
PS C:\Users\ross.williams\Downloads\Python> .\.venv\Scripts\activate
(.venv) PS C:\Users\ross.williams\Downloads\Python> 

enter image description here
After I run import pandas as pd my terminal outputs
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\ross.williams\Downloads\Python\zipcode_enrich.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

and .venv gets dropped from my terminal window.
I've installed pandas, pip install pandas and it successfully installs. I've also installed 'wheel' successfully. Not sure if I actually had to do that.
enter image description here
enter image description here
My Python version:
PS C:\Users\ross.williams\Downloads\Python> python
Python 3.12.0 (tags/v3.12.0:0fb18b0, Oct  2 2023, 13:03:39) [MSC v.1935 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.


I'm assuming you're using VS Code as your IDE? From past experience, changing venv in the terminal does not change the environment detected(?) by the IDE. Try looking up the "Select and activate an environment" section here and select your desired venv: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments
Also, make sure that pandas is installed in the venv, not outside in "base" python!

If you want VS Code to run with venv awareness, you can't just manually activate the venv in your terminal: that only activates it for that one, specific terminal. Instead, make sure the official Python extension is installed, and then use that to activate your venv project-wide.

@Talos0248 OP's not only changing venv in the terminal. You can see in the screenshots that they're using "Select Interpreter" in the IDE and that the right interpreter shows as selected (bottom right ish).

TL;DR for the linked question: You're using Code Runner, which doesn't support VSC's selected Python environment (AFAIK). Use the official Python extension instead.

What happens when you do import pandas outside of the venv i.e. in a regular Python console that uses the global Python interpreter on your computer?
I've had similar issues on a lot of different machines I've worked with. Most of the time it is usually an issue with the virtualenv or an issue with the Python installation.

What issue with the virtualenv?

"has not added Python to PATH" - That's not it, otherwise OP wouldn't be getting a traceback from Python.

Why does it matter what the global interpreter does when OP wants to use the venv?

@aconfusedtortoise, this worked. I dont know why. So when I reinstalled the pandas and it gave me a pop up notice "You may have intalled python packages into your global environment, Which can cause conflicts between package versions. Would you like to create a virtual environment with these packages to isolate your dependencies?" Not sure if that has anything to do with anything. From watching a youtube vido I though I had to use a virtual env to use pandas. I guess not. So I guess I can move forward with my project. Thanks

@wjandrea The problem arises due to conflicts between global environment and the virtualenv. I have stumbled upon cases where it appears as if the user is inside the venv, but the packages are installed to the global interpreter. The easiest way to resolve this "weird bug" is to first check if Python is in PATH, create a new virtual environment and try again.

@RevOps608 "I though[t] I had to use a virtual env to use pandas" - Well, you don't have to, but you probably should. Your project might rely on the feature set of a specific version of Pandas, which is easiest to manage in a virtualenv. The other thing about using the global environment (and I've experienced this myself) is that you might want to install a ton of different packages for different projects, and those packages might have conflicting dependencies, which means they can't all be installed at the same time. But if you split them up, then that works.

@aconfusedtortoise I'm not following. What does that have to do with this answer?

@wjandrea What are you referring to?

@aconfusedtortoise I don't see how your comment relates to your answer. The advice seems to be totally different.

@wjandrea I am totally new to this platform, so I am sorry if my comment is out of place. Still learning the rules and guidelines, meanwhile trying to be helpful.
